# Why we need the concept of degree of freedom in various statistical analysis?

Tags: degrees-of-freedom

I understand what degree of freedom means. However I want to know why we need to adjust for degree of freedom in many statistical analysis such as; simply in sample variance calculation where we use (n-1) instead of n or in other analysis such as; ANOVA. If we do not adjust for this concept what consequence this can have on our analysis and interpretation of data. I would be very kind if someone would answer this with simplified example. Thank you.

Comment: For example, a [$\chi^2$ distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chi-squared_distribution) is underspecified without a degree of freedom parameter.  What is your difficulty with the explanation at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Degrees_of_freedom_%28statistics%29 ?

Comment: That seems too complex for me. If someone could explain at least the effect of degree of freedom on sample variance computation e.g. if we wouldn't take into account (n-1) how our estimate would be erroneous?